# Vagrant provision cannot finish

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, apt-get

I'm trying to run `vagrant provision` but I cannot install a package with `apt-get`. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Configuring libc6:amd64 ├────────────────────────┐│││ There are services installed on your system which need to be restarted    ││ when certain libraries, such as libpam, libc, and libssl, are upgraded.   ││ Since these restarts may cause interruptions of service for the system,   ││ you will normally be prompted on each upgrade for the list of services    ││ you wish to restart.  You can choose this option to avoid being││ prompted; instead, all necessary restarts will be done for you││ automatically so you can avoid being asked questions on each library││ upgrade.││││ Restart services during package upgrades without asking?││││<Yes><No>│││└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I think the error comes from this line:

```
sudo apt-get install -yq libpq-dev python-dev --allow-unauthenticated -qq
```

I have tried to add `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive pt-get install -yq libpq-dev python-dev --allow-unauthenticated -qq
```

But I still get the same error. Any ideas? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in `vagrant.`

Comment: For testing purposes, use apt-get -force-yes

Comment: fixed! thanks!! though now I'm facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776695/vagrant-cannot-export-nfs-folders too :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last resort and for testing purposes, you can change the apt-get command to:

```
apt-get -force-yes
```