# Vagrant cannot export NFS folders

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, nfs

I'm trying to run a `vagrant up` but I'm encountering this problem:

[image]

Here is the content of my `/etc/exports` file:

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 9eddace4-3458-4a4f-bc5b-056ba38c6372
"/System/Volumes/Data/Users/alfredo/Documents/GitHub/badger-docrouter" -alldirs -mapall=501:20 172.28.128.27
"/System/Volumes/Data/Users/alfredo/Documents/GitHub/badger-scripts" -alldirs -mapall=501:20 172.28.128.27
"/System/Volumes/Data/Users/alfredo/Documents/GitHub/knowledge_base" -alldirs -mapall=501:20 172.28.128.27
"/System/Volumes/Data/Users/alfredo/Documents/GitHub/tile-server" -alldirs -mapall=501:20 172.28.128.27
# VAGRANT-END: 501 9eddace4-3458-4a4f-bc5b-056ba38c6372
```

The result of `vagrant box list`

```
ubuntu/trusty64 (virtualbox, 20190514.0.0)
ubuntu/xenial64 (virtualbox, 20201104.0.0)
ubuntu/xenial64 (virtualbox, 20210316.0.0)
```

Version of `vagrant`: 2.2.14
Version of `VirtualBox`: 6.1
Version of `Guest Additions`: 5.1.38

And the mapping of directories in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8124, host: 8124
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5900, host: 5900
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"


  config.vm.synced_folder "../badger-docrouter/", "/home/vagrant/badgerdev", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../tile-server/", "/home/vagrant/tile-server", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../badger-scripts/", "/home/vagrant/badgerscripts", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../knowledge_base/", "/home/vagrant/knowledge_base", type: "nfs"
```

I'm using `macOS BigSur Version 11.2.3(20D91)`.

Does someone know how to fix it? Do you need more info?

**UPDATE**

I have fixed the permisions problem, but know I have the following error:

```
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
mount -o vers=3,udp 172.28.128.1:/System/Volumes/Data/Users/alfredo/Documents/GitHub/badger-docrouter /home/vagrant/badgerdev
Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:
mount.nfs: mounting 172.28.128.1:/System/Volumes/Data/Users/alfredo/Documents/GitHub/badger-docrouter failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

I have checked it and that directory exist in my machine.